# SQL Query - Get records with null values (but make sure they dont have any other records that match the key with a value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates

So I am writing a query whereby I need to get all records within a table that have null or '' values for two fields...

File and Postcode.

My problem is I have duplicate records, all queries I have written so far will return me a record with a null or '' file and postcode field however one of the duplicates (based on email field) does have a file/postcode value.

I need to only get those records where all instances have a null file/postcode value

```
  SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL FROM Results R
  WHERE
    ( ISNULL(R.Postcode, '') = ''
        AND
      ISNULL(R.File, '') = ''
     )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM Results RR
        WHERE RR.Email = R.Email
        AND (
            ISNULL(R.Postcode, '') <> ''
            AND
            ISNULL(R.File, '') <> ''
        )
    )
    ORDER BY R.Email
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a blind stab in the dark here, but I *suspect* a `HAVING` clause with a conditional aggregate will resolve this one:

```
SELECT Email
FROM Results
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Postcode IS NOT NULL AND Postcode != '' THEN 1 END) = 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN [File] IS NOT NULL AND [File] != '' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Note, also, that I haven't used `ISNULL` (or `COALESCE`) in the logic, but instead used boolean logic. This is actually important as having functions like `ISNULL` wrapped around a column in your `WHERE` cause the query to be non-SARGable; meaning that the indexes on your table can't be used to aid the data engine filter to the correct rows and instead it has to perform a full scan of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would express the `having` clause as:

```
HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(Postcode, '')) = 0 AND
       COUNT(NULLIF([File], '')) = 0 ;
```